# Add xmlns attribute to an XML file.

Tags: php

I want to save namespace attribute 'xmlns' in xml doc. 
Here is what I have tried doing..

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_index = $xml->createElement("urlset");
$root->appendChild(
$xml->createAttribute('xmlns'))->appendChild(
$xml->createTextNode('http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'));
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     $xml_sitemap = $xml->createElement("url");
     $xml_loc = $xml->createElement("loc", 'http://test.com/sitemaps/'.$link[$i]);
     $xml_index->appendChild( $xml_sitemap );
     $xml_sitemap->appendChild( $xml_loc );
}
$xml_index->appendChild( $xml_sitemap );
$xml_sitemap->appendChild( $xml_loc );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_index );
$xml->save('\tmp\test.xml');
```

Can someone please help me? 
The format I want is below

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     <sitemap>
           <loc>http://test.com/sitemaps/urlset_start10000.xml</loc>
     </sitemap>
     <sitemap>
           <loc>http://test.com/sitemaps/urlset_start20000.xml</loc>
     </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Output I get is, without xmlns attribute.

Answer (score 0):

as [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php) states createElementNS should do the job

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$element = $dom->createElementNS('http://www.example.com/XFoo', 'xfoo:test', 'This is the root element!');
$dom->appendChild($element);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what she want. She want to add xmlns attribute in the node not as a value.